# define is not a function?

Tags: mysql, nodejs

tengo un problema con el ORM SEQUIRALIZE estoy usando nodejs y lo que necesito es importar la configuración de la bd para el modelo rol, ya que no se si la estoy importando mal pero al hacerlo recibe este error?. adjunto captures para mayor comprensión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, tu código en texto y no en imagenes. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, si cambias esto: `const db = require('../index').sequelize;` por esto otro: `const db = require('../index');` (sin el `sequelize`), debería funcionar correctamente el `db.define()`. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio Gracias, soy nueva en stackoverflow, ya hice lo que tu dices y no me funciona.. nuevamente gracias por la sugerencia realizare los cambios.

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu problema, es decir, a mi me funciona. En la imagen logro apreciar que tienes más de un archivo llamado `rol.js`. Deberías usar un complemento para diferenciarlos, por ejemplo: `rol.model.js`, `rol.controller.js`, etc. Es una sugerencia. En cuanto al problema, la verdad no entiendo que puede estar pasando, ya que haciendo exactamente lo que tu haces, da el error, pero haciendo la corrección que te indico en mi comentario anterior, no ocurre el error. Verifica que ese sea el único sitio donde cometes el error. Saludos